# Group function of Mongo DBCollection does not create separate arrays while reducing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a group function call like below:

```
coll.group(
    {"eventid":1}, 
    {},  
    {participants:new Array(), winners:new Array()},  
    function(cur, result) {  
        result.participants++; 
        if (cur.status == "W"){result.winners++} 
    }, 
    false, 
    function(err, data) {}
);
```

The above works perfectly fine, where I get the count of participants and winners for each "eventid". However, when I change the code to below where I want to get the list of participant names and winner names for each "eventid", I don't get the desired result. Every list has entries from every eventid. How do I solve this problem? The array seems to be reused across keys (eventid) and does not seem to be created new for each unique key.

```
coll.group(
    {"eventid":1}, 
    {},  
    {participants:new Array(), winners:new Array()},  
    function(cur, result) {  
        result.participants.push(cur.teamname); 
        if (cur.status == "W"){result.winners.push(cur.teamname)} 
    }, 
    false, 
    function(err, data) {}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would not be to use `.group()` at all, the reason being that it relies on JavaScript processing in order to get the results. Since this runs through an interpreter it does not run as quickly as native code methods.

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) uses native methods and therefore should process much faster. You could take a couple of approaches to this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Group with possible "false" conditions
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$eventid",
        "Participants": { "$push": "$teamname" },
        "Winners": { 
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$status", "W" ] },
                    "$teamname",
                    false
                ]
            }
        }
    }},

    // Unwind one array
    { "$unwind": "$Winners" },

    // Filter out the "false" results
    { "$match": { "Winners": { "$ne": false } } },

    // Group back again
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "Participants": { "$first": "$Participants" },
        "Winners": { "$first": "$Winners" }
    }}
])
```

Or by the [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) in MongoDB 2.6 where possible:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$eventid",
        "Participants": { "$push": "$teamname" },
        "Winners": { 
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$status", "W" ] },
                    "$teamname",
                    false
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "Participants": 1,
        "Winners": {
            "$setDifference": [
                "$Winners",
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Faster than JavaScript evaluation at any rate, and does not suffer the restrictions that `.group()` has.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the setDifference code of yours. It worked! But I had to upgrade to 2.6. I was using 2.0.4. That was one reason why I was insistent on group.

Comment: @RamkumarManavalan The way to do it prior to the MongoDB 2.2 release would be with the `.mapreduce()` method instead. There is more control there than `.group()`. But the release is really quite aged so upgrading and using the aggregation framework is the way to proceed.